# Django: Test session key before redirection

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, http-redirect

I'm creating a session key after posting to a view, and then I redirect to the same view, clearing that key.

I want to test for the creation of the key in `request.session`, but I can't, because after the redirection, the key is removed.

**View**

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # ...
        request.session['my_key'] = 'my_value'
        return redirect(reverse('my_view'))
        # ...

    if request.session.get('my_key', None):
        del request.session['my_key']

    return render(request)
```

**Test**

```
def my_test(self):
    response = self.client.post('my_view')
    self.assertEqual(self.client.session.get('my_key'), 'my_value')
```

As `self.client.post` goes to the redirect chain, the key is removed, and the test fails.

Is there a way to `self.client.post` and stop after the redirection, so the test passes?

Comment: Where in your view do you have a redirect?

Comment: You can check the `response.redirect_chain`.

Comment: I thought by default `self.client.post()` does not follow redirects and you have to explicitly set `follow=True` to get the response after the redirect. So if your view is returning a redirect (which I don't see) then `response` in your test should be the 302 response and the session key still set. Add `self.assertEqual(302, response.status_code)` and you'll see.

Comment: Also your assertion is wrong: you need to check the session `self.client.session.get('my_key')`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I forgot the redirect line. Updated.

Comment: @dirkgroten, I updated the post fixing the assertion.

Comment: @Caco your code should work. What is `response.status_code`?

Comment: responses.status_code == 302. As you commented above I also expected the response would not `follow` the redirect statement, but it does.

Comment: It doesn't follow, since the status_code is 302. Otherwise it would have been 200.

Comment: I just copied exactly your code into a quick test project. The test passes. The session variable is set correctly.

Comment: In other words, if your test fails, you're not giving us the full picture. You will need to give us all the code of you view, not just a snippet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197960/discussion-between-caco-and-dirkgroten).